# compilation problems with unordered set

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

I am trying to use an `unordered_set` from the C++ std library. I am using the std namespace.

```
using namespace std;
```

The `unordered_set` is within a function of mine. I would like to use it to memoize some values.

```
int do_crazy_calculations(int n) {
    static unordered_set<int> done_before;
    done_before::iterator node_found = done_before.find(n);

    // n has not been seen before, so do calculations and memoize the result.
    if (node_found == done_before.end()) {
        int result = actually_do_calculations(n);
        done_before.insert(n, result);
        return result;
    }

    // n has already been seen before, just return the memoized value.
    else {
        return node_found.get();
    }
}
```

However, I am getting this compilation error:

> CplusplusExperiment.cpp: In function `'int do_crazy_calculations(int)'`:
>   CplusplusExperiment.cpp:10:10: error: `'unordered_set'` does not name a type
>   make: *** [CplusplusExperiment.o] Error 1

However, I did assign a type to `unordered_set` - `int` right? What does this error mean?

Comment: Did you `#include <unordered_set>`?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-std=c++0x`?

Comment: `std::unordered_set<int>::insert` doesn't take two `int`s, it only takes one. Maybe you are thinking of `std::map`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. First of all, never do `using namespace std` -- it's a source of a thousand frustrating errors.
2. `done_before` really doesn't name a type, it names a variable. To name a type you could use `typedef unordered_set<int> done_before_type`, then `done_before_type::iterator` will work.
3. You need to include the header `<unordered_set>`
4. Finally, you need a compiler that supports it (VS 2010+, GCC 4.4+) or a proper usage via Boost or TR1 libraries.

Answer (score 4):

should be `unordered_set<int>::iterator node_found = ...`

I usually use a typedef to simplify naming of templated variables:

```
typedef unordered_set<int> t_done_before;
static t_done_before done_before;
t_done_before::iterator node_found = ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that was something to correct. The same compilation error is occuring though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, unordered_set is in TR1 or C++11.

And second, you are declaring the set inside your function and then testing for some value in it. What's the point? The set's gonna be empty each time you call the function. EDIT: sorry, didn't notice it was static.

Comment: But it's static, right? Shouldn't it maintain state across function calls?